# How to survive background execution limit

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, android-location

There are some questions in my mind would like someone to answer and clarify:
I have background service that sends coordinates of location every second from background and updating location on another device like happens in driver customer model, what will happen to this app under background execution limit? And how will I survive this execution limit and after that what will be behaviour of my application? Will I have to start forground service for this?

Also what if I disable location permissions for this app frim settings while its working and sending coordinates, what will happen? Moreover can I notify user that location permission is disable and service is stoped?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- If you need frequent location updates (like for tracking exact path, the user was running) you definitely need a foreground service. Just add notification to your service and tell it to go foreground, displaying said notification:

```
startForeground(yourId, yourNotifcation)
```

- If you need to know, when user happens to be in / outside some area, than Geofences are your best bet. Say, you want to know, whether he have left a train station. Or is nearby a certain shop.
- If you need just infrequent (like every 15 - 20 minutes or more) updates of user location, than you can do this via WorkManager

Comment: And what if user disable location permission from settings while service is running, can I notify user that permission is disabled?

Comment: AFAIK this will terminate your app process.

Comment: Any reference to this that app process will stop when I disable permission

Comment: I do not know any way to intercept this event reliably (however I did not try, so maybe there is).. 
However your process death will be kind of visible to the user - while your foreground process is running, it will be showing notification. When user disables geolocation permission for your app, the notification will disappear.